# precision vs covariance

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, covariance

I have seen that when modelling the likelihood term with a multivariate Gaussian tend to parameterise the Gaussian with the inverse covariance matrix (precision) rather than the covariance matrix, claiming it might be easier for certain calculations typically done in Bayesian inferencing.

Does anyone know what they are alluding to?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [conjugate prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) for the inverse of the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution, which is the [Wishart distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution). With conjugate priors there is a [closed form solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for the [posterior distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability), which means you do not need to resort to more complex estimation methods like [MCMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo).

Comment: Yes, but you also have the inverse Wishart for the covariance matrix parameter as the conjugate prior.

Comment: This is true. The choice of parameterizing the normal in terms of precision or variance (or even standard deviation) is informed partially by the algebra of the particular problem (Rubin's famous 8 Schools problem, for example, takes precision-weighted averages of the data). Either can be convenient in some context. Another consideration is programming language: in R, the normal uses standard deviation; Bugs uses precision; `stan` uses variance.